# Time printed in log file is it executed time for that statement or log time in the file. Because log4j2 do logging async

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, log4j

I am checking performance issues from log, i see some of my threads are taking more time, sub-sequences log statement printing with >1 sec gap. to analysces this can i below timestamp in the logs. pattern is [%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX}]. so i have doubt
Time printed in log file is it executed time for that statement or log time in the file. Because log4j2 do logging async?

I read some of log4j2 documents and not found this information. Can someone please let me know?